# improper integrals calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

for a do i change 0 to t and take the limit as the integral goes to t? because the ln of 0 doesnt exist but the ln of 1 does

and for b do i split it up as two integrals, one from negative infinity to 0 and the other from zero to infinity? or would i have to use t for both and take the limit?

oIts been a while since ive done these so im not quite sure how to approach them.

Comment: On the second, splitting is probably best general strategy. However, you can find $\int_{-A}^B x^3e^{-x^4}\,dx$, and show that the limit as $A$ and $B$ get very large **independently** exists. It would be a mistake to integrate from $-A$ to $A$ and take the limit, though in this particular case you would get the same answer.

Comment: For (b), they probably want you to split the integral and take each limit.  However, it will be of value to take note of the symmetry of the integrand function $x^3 \cdot e^{-x^4}$ and what integrating symmetrically about $x = 0$ does.

Comment: since the function is odd do the two parts cancel each other out?

Answer (score 1):

Your first thoughts on both problems are correct, assuming e.g. you mean "make the limits of integration $t$ and $1$, integrate, then take the limit as $t$ goes to $0$".

Another way to do the second problem is to make the limits $s$ and $t$, and take the double limit as $(s,t)$ goes to $(-\infty, +\infty)$. This doesn't amount to much of a difference in terms of calculation, though.

Using $t$ and $-t$ for the limits in the second problem is a different (but related) idea, called the "Cauchy principal value", which is sometimes useful when the improper integral doesn't exist.

Comment: how would i take double limits?

Comment: If you've not started multivariable calculus, it's probably not worth worrying too much about it. In this *particular* case (but not in general!), it would simplify to $$\lim_{s \to -\infty} \lim_{t \to +\infty} \cdots$$, and so you could just compute the inner limit on its own, and then compute the outer limit of the result.

Comment: if I don'tknow double limits howdoI approach this problem?

Comment: @user: `Your first thoughts on both problems are correct`